# Re-applying QField changes that have been lost (more than 50 at once)

Tags: qgis, qfield-cloud

Recently when I synchronized my project from QField Cloud the points would not appear on my local computer device or my remote tablet. Is there a faster way to re-apply changes on QField Cloud than selecting all and reapplying the changes to 50 at a time per page?